# Bootstrap row not covering width with hamburger in it

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, nav

Bootstrap 4

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-6">Logo Here</div>
<div class="col-6 text-right">Hamburger Here</div>
<div class="col-12 text-right">Expandable Menu sits in here</div>
</div><!-- Closes Row -->
</div><!-- Closes Container -->
```

This seems pretty straight forward. Logo on the left in mobile. Hamburger pushed right in the other col-6. In theory the row doesn't expand the full width of the container UNTIL you click on the hamburger and expand the navigation menu. A row should cover full width regardless of whether something is pushing it or not. It almost acts like it EXPANDS a bit when clicked because the logo is getting bigger.
Am I missing something here in the row->col dynamic when a expandable nav is involved?

[image: Notice location of hamburger]

[image: Now hamburger has gone out where it belongs.]

Comment: you could use the size in the class... like `col-sm-6` and `col-xs-12` so it goes full width when the device width is smaller... if you want a full row then you should not have two col-6 inside it... that means exactly 2 coluns with half-width each, 50%...

Comment: Why aren't you using the Navbar?